# What is are the tradeoffs of developing under Windows CE 6.0 vs Windows Mobile 6.1

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have a Windows .NET application that I plan to "port" and tailor to a mobile device.  The application consists of a standalone .NET program that works with a barcode scanner, has a simple UI and records the scans to a file.  There is also a Windows Service that synchronizes data to a server using web services (proprietary sync protocol).  Memory/disk/network requirements are rather minimal.  We have no existing WinCE or WinMo code bases and do not require other applications on the device.

The device I'm considering using is a Motorola MC3100 mobile computer with a laser scanner, WiFi, and a color touchscreen.  I have the option of getting the device with Windows CE 6.0 or Windows Mobile 6.1.

What factors should I consider in making this decision?
Which is easier for the user?
Which would have a better development/debugging/configuration stack?

Answer (score 4):

WinMo is a platform build on CE.  Basically it's a new shell and some "special" APIs (none of which you can't do without WinMo, so it's not really magic).  WinMo has a defined set of applications, libraries, etc so it's more standardized and if you want to run your app on multiple devices it *might* benefit you going that way (but in this specific case I doubt it would buy you much).

Unless you have specific need for WinMo, definitely go with generic Windows CE.  That way you don't have to fight the WinMo shell and platform all the time.  It's certainly easier to get a CE device to behave itself.

Answer (score 2):

Advantages for Windows CE:

- More flexibility. If for example you want to build a kiosk mode application, this is much easier done with Windows CE.

Advantages of Windows Mobile:

- The Home Screen and the User Interface in general better fit a mobile device. With Windows CE you'll start with a desktop like the one you see in a PC.
- Chances are that the users will find the UI more familiar.
- It is easier to find third party applications.
- A device needs to go through a certification phase in order to be able to get the Windows Mobile logo. I will feel more secure with a Windows Mobile than with a Windows CE device. Your device can offer both, which I think is a very good thing.

In general, if you want to build something quickly and don't want to invest much time on it, then go for Windows Mobile. If on the other hand you are building a complicated application/system, need to install services and a number of applications, then go for Windows CE.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Windows Mobile 6.1 is a more specialized version of Windows CE to target mobile devices. Windows CE 6.0 is an operating system for embedded systems in general. So if you only plan to target mobile phones/smartphones so best stick to Windows Mobile.

I made some experience in developing a Windows Mobile app with the Visual Studio extension for Mobile development. You can easily simulate your software without having to install it on the device.

Best place to start for WM6 development is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 0):

I would say go for Win CE, as that will work on Win Mobile as well.

Comment: Not true always. There are things you can do in Windows CE that are prohibited in Windows Mobile or at least are more difficult to do.