# Advantage of developing under Windows Mobile 6 over Windows CE 6?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have a small .NET CF C# project at hand which gives me choice - Windows CE 6 or Windows Mobile 6.1

The application is for a single device (Symbol MC3xxx) so it doesnt need to be compatible with many devices with different features. All is compact and will use only functionality which is available in the device.

What would be **advantage of picking Windows Mobile** for such a project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Develop for Windows CE5.0 or Windows Mobile 5.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262834/develop-for-windows-ce5-0-or-windows-mobile-5-0)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016402/windows-ce-vs-windows-mobile

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349685/net-mobile-vs-windows-mobile

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166084/what-is-are-the-tradeoffs-of-developing-under-windows-ce-6-0-vs-windows-mobile-6

Comment: @ctacke thank you for your vigilance... however first 3 links are nothing to do with my question. they are about - what is win ce and what is win mobile. my question is about developing for them. also win ce/mob 5 are different from win ce/mob 6. the last link is good match but it was not answered, was it?

Comment: Knowing the difference between the two greatly helps one to understand which you'd want to target.  WinMo 6.x is running CE 5.0, so they are relevant for that reason. And just becasue a question doesn't have an accepted answer doesn't mean there's no information to be gleaned.  I didn't provide a direct answer here (I'm completely capable of doing that) becasue I felt that the aggregation of the links above provides an answer.  If you feel they do not (and that's totally ok), then elaborate on your question and ask us specifically what you want to know that they don't cover and we'll help out.

Comment: Why the childish retorts?  I'm simply asking you to be more clear in your question.  This is like asking "which is better for building houses, bricks or boards?"  Both have advantages, and without us knowing more about what you're after, it's difficult to answer.  The links I provided give a lot of information comparing and contrasting platforms and even descriptions of which someone would choose and why.  Evidently you want a more elaborate answer than "which would you choose and why" and I'm simply trying to understand what more you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question has an already-accepted answer, but one thing to consider is that I think you'll find more Microsoft-provided WindowsMobile-only assemblies available (things like GPS, PowerManagement, etc).  It's nice to not have to reinvent the wheel sometimes.

Food for thought...

Comment: that kinda answer i wanted from very beginning. thanks mate